# Create a Form That Will Add Products to the Cart Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm a beginner in PHP, I need to create a custom form on the homepage of a Wordpress site (which has Woocommerce Store). In this form will have fields:

Product Field: dropdown to get the product name automatically (only the name, will be 15 products only)

Quantity Field: The user enters the quantity of the product.

Price Field: input that gets the total value of the product automatically when the user selects the product name and product quantity. It has to automatically update the total amount according to the quantity entered

Button: and a add button to the cart that sends the visitor to the Woocommerce cart page with the cart filled with the form information.

How to do this? Is there a plugin or just by code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean a normal shop with products the user can add to your cart? Or do you need something like that the user can pay to create a product? Not sure what you want mate..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check out the question guidelines at: stackoverflow.com/help . I would suggest asking more specific questions and including code in the question to help other users better understand what the issue is. It is always easier if others can also reproduce the scenario. Instead of asking 'how to do X', it's better to try an approach and then ask 'I have been trying Y to achieve X but am facing this issue Z'.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Thanks for answer. A normal shop. I want the person to be able to make a quotation through a fixed form at the top of the page. When she selects the product in the dropdown, enter the quantity of product she wants, the form will show the total and she can click add to cart. Then it will be redirected to the Woocommerce cart page to proceed to the checkout

Comment: @skbrhmn Thank you for the advice. But I have no idea yet where to start. I'm a super beginner at php = /